# PouchDB not syncing deletions when revs_limit is greater than 0

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a local pouchDB of tasks. Worked pretty well until I tried to set up sync with IBM Cloudant noSQL. The major problem so far is with the remove() method, which I have written like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#taskList li .delete", function(){

    db.remove(id,rev);
    refreshTasks();

});
```

The method works perfectly when sync is off, but as soon as I activate sync with the lines below, It won't remove the task from both local and remote. I'm running PouchDB syncing with this code:

```
db.sync(remote_db, {
  live: true,
  retry: true
}).on('change', function (change) {
  // yo, something changed!
}).on('paused', function (info) {
  // replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection
}).on('active', function (info) {
  // replication was resumed
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)
});
```

My database is created with this:

```
var db = new PouchDB('tasks', {revs_limit: 1, auto_compaction: true});
```

Now when I create the database with a revs_limit of 0, it works again.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 6):

When you remove a document from Pouch, the underlying operation is similar to an update - the update contains a deletion "tombstone" revision that must be synchronised back to the server.

By setting `revs_limit:1`, the local database will only keep track of the most recent revision for each document, including this deletion, so when the sync occurs it won't know which parent revision to attach the deletion to. This isn't an error condition in Couch/Cloudant - it would just create a conflicted document on the server.

I suggest creating the database without changing the default `revs_limit`. Really, the only scenario where that makes sense is when you have documents that are immutable - i.e. they will never be updated / deleted.